# Navigating between panels in scala

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

I want to know how to navigate between panels in scala swinng.  the current code I have is:

```
 val top = new MainFrame {

     title = "Predator and Prey Agent simulation"      
     val buttonExit = new Button {
     text = "Exit"
  //foo
 }

    val buttonStart = new Button {      
      top.visible = false
      text = "Play"     
    }
```

I want the buttonStart button to take me to another frame that I define in another class.  How exactly do I implement that in scala.  I get a recursive value error from what I have above.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to start a new window, or just switch the contents of the current window? If it's the latter, [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is what you're looking for.

Which line in your example causes the error? I suspect it's the `top.visible = false`. This would be because the compiler needs to know the type of `top` but can't infer it because you have a reference to it in its definition. Adding a type annotation should fix this error:

```
val top: MainFrame = new MainFrame {
```